# Node.js TCP Socket Server on AppFog

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, appfog

Given the following simple TCP socket server running on AppFog that echoes back whatever the client sends.

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
  socket.pipe(socket);
});

var port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 80;
server.listen(port);
console.log('Server running at ' + port);
```

I can't seem to connect to the server at all. It works fine on my local development machine.

Does AppFog support what I am trying to do at all? I'm relatively new to Node.js so I can't say for sure the code is correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js TCP Socket Server on the Cloud \[Heroku/AppFog\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458943/node-js-tcp-socket-server-on-the-cloud-heroku-appfog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. The long answer is in this other StakOverflow question: [Node.js TCP Socket Server on the Cloud [Heroku/AppFog]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458943/node-js-tcp-socket-server-on-the-cloud-heroku-appfog/)