# Heroku and Twisted

Tags: python, heroku, twisted, telnet

I am trying to learn Twisted, a Python framework, and I want to put a basic application online that, when it receive a message sends it back. I decided to use Heroku to host it, and I followed the instructions on their docs.

```
import os
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()

port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
reactor.listenTCP(port, EchoFactory(), interface = '0.0.0.0')
reactor.run()
```

Its all working except (and I know this is a stupid question), how do I send a message to it? When I am working locally I just do `telnet localhost <port>`, but now I have no idea.
Also, since heroku connects to a random port how can I know what port it connects my app to?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Twisted, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do is supported on Heroku. Heroku currently only supports HTTP[S] requests and not raw TCP. There are more details in the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13469883/2942).

If you wanted to connect to your app, you should use the `myapp.herokuapp.com` host name or any custom domain that you've added.

Answer (score 0):

"Pure Python applications, such as headless processes and evented web frameworks like Twisted, are fully supported on Cedar."

Reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support